# Why doesn't uvt-kvm --run-script-once work when run on a 14.04 host building a more recent guest?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual host, and I'm building guests on it with uvt-kvm. I have a small script I want them to run on first start. The command line looks something like this:

`uvt-kvm create --run-script-once $bootstrap $guestname release=$release`

When the release is 'trusty' (i.e. same release as the host), the bootstrap script runs as expected. For more recent releases, the guest builds and boots but does not run the script.

Why does this happen, and what can I do about it?